# Subscription to RxSwift Observable<VideoCaptureOutput> not triggering onNext()

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, rx-swift

I'd like to use RxSwift to process video frames captured from the iPhone camera. I'm using a community maintained project, https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxAVFoundation, which bridges AVFoundation (used to capture camera output) and RxSwift.

I'm trying to just print a dummy log statement whenever new video frames get written to the output buffer. The following is my ViewController. I configure the AVCaptureSession, set up the Rx chain, then start the session. However, the print statement in the .next case is never triggered. I reached out to the project owner. Is the below code correct? Here's the Reactive extension for the AVCaptureSession class from the community maintained project: https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxAVFoundation/blob/master/RxAVFoundation/AVCaptureSession%2BRx.swift

```
//  ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import RxSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // capture session
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private var videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.videoDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back)
    
        session
            .rx
            .configure(captureDevice: videoDevice)
    
        let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
        
        let videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]
        session
            .rx
            .videoCaptureOutput(settings: videoSettings)
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe { [unowned self] (event) in
                switch event {
                    case .next(let captureOutput):
                        print("got a frame")
                    case .error(let error):
                        print("error: %@", "\(error)")
                    case .completed:
                        break // never happens
                }
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
        session
            .rx
            .startRunning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for permission to use the camera?

Comment: Yes I am - Info.plist has been updated and a prompt pops up requesting access to the camera. @DanielT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you've defined your `DisposeBag` locally inside `viewDidLoad` as soon as `viewDidLoad` finishes all the subscriptions added to the bag are disposed.

Declare your `DisposeBag` as an instance variable of the `ViewController` to fix:

```
...
// capture session
private let session = AVCaptureSession()
private var videoDevice: AVCaptureDevice!

private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ...
```

Using `.debug()` is a great way to catch this kind of thing as it will print all events including disposal, e.g.:

```
session
    .rx
    .videoCaptureOutput(settings: videoSettings)
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .debug("Video Capture Output Observable:")
    .subscribe { [unowned self] (event) in
        switch event {
            case .next(let captureOutput):
                print("got a frame")
            case .error(let error):
                print("error: %@", "\(error)")
            case .completed:
                break // never happens
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```